# problem with query -php/json

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have this code, and the output is: `{"round (avg (salary), 0)":"1750"}`

```
function tableOne() {

    $query = mysql_query("select round (avg (salary), 0) from worker, formation_area where id_formation_area=1") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $result = $row;

    echo json_encode($result);
}

tableOne(); 

?>
```

but i need something like this: {1750}.

Any help?

Comment: try doing a `print_r($result);` so you can see the data you're working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function tableOne() {

    $query = mysql_query("select round(avg (salary), 0) as `round_avg` from worker, formation_area where id_formation_area=1") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $result = $row['round_avg'];

    echo json_encode($result);
}

tableOne();
```

Remember json needs a `something: something_else` so you might get an error here since now there is no array being encoded